# Selecting controls from a case-cohort study when location is important

Tags: epidemiology, case-control-study, observational-study

I am looking at the causes of a disease in cows, both 'environmental' (ie ground-drainage, bedding type etc) and 'biological' (previous disease, sex, weight etc). Most environmental variables are the same per barn, if not per farm. Biological variables are measured per individual. I have 5 farms, containing 2 to 6 barns, each containing 5 to 100 cows.

I know which cows have the disease, and that it is more common in 2 of the 5 farms (hinting at an environmental cause maybe...).

I 'think' i want to run everything in one model, a GLMM with binomial response for disease (yes/no) for each individual. Individual ID/barn/farm as a nested random effect, everything else as fixed effects.

So, my questions are....

1. Given that location is important (for the environmental variables), can I select all of the disease cows (even though I know they're clustered)? Or do I need to just select individuals completely at random? (occurrence isn't that high)
2. If I CAN select all of the disease cows, how do I select the controls? Instinctively I want to select roughly the same number of individuals as the disease cows, at random, from all 5 farms. I feel there must be a bias in there somewhere though, based on the fact that I know the location of the disease cows (so heavy sampling from diseased farms) whilst the rest are selected at random...but maybe thats the nature of it???

Any help would be greatly appreciated! For those of a visual persuasion like me,
 here is a handy picture - note that the proportions of cows are totally made up at this point :) [image]